# Does Bitcoin Core support HD wallet?

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core, bip32-hd-wallets

Does Bitcoin Core (bitcoind or bitcoin-cli) support HD wallet?

Can Bitcoin Core ...

Q1. create HD wallets?
Q2. import HD wallets from other wallet software?
Q3. watch HD wallet? (watch transaction or notify changes)

Comment: I found the pull request for HD(BIP32).  
  
Add HD/Bip32 support by jonasschnelli · Pull Request #6265 · bitcoin/bitcoin  
[https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/6265](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/6265)

Comment: Minimal support is expected for 0.13: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/396f9d629662ae8c95bc576000166f5b8941ef0b/doc/release-notes.md#hierarchical-deterministic-key-generation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update: As of bitcoin-core 13.0, core uses HD wallets by default.

Answer (score 3):

> create HD wallets?

No, but this is something being worked on.

> import HD wallets from other wallet software?

No, HD wallets being transportable between software like this is unlikely due to the wide range of implementations. An Electrum seed is unlike an Armory seed is unlike a Bread wallet seed.

> watch HD wallet? (watch transaction or notify changes)

Only if you `importaddress` for a large number of future addresses which is cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

In the newest release of [bitcoin core 0.16](https://bitcoincore.org/en/2018/02/26/release-0.16.0/) they have said it [support HD Wallet by default](https://bitcoincore.org/en/2018/02/26/release-0.16.0/#hd-wallets-by-default). this is a backward incompatible change because it says:

> HD-wallets by default: 
>   Due to a backward-incompatible change in the wallet database, wallets created with version 0.16.0 will be rejected by previous versions. Also, version 0.16.0 will only create hierarchical deterministic (HD) wallets. Note that this only applies to new wallets; wallets made with previous versions will not be upgraded to be HD.

Comment: You're confused. All wallets created by 0.13 (by defaultt) and up are HD wallets; wallets created earlier were not. 0.16 only removed the ability to create new non-HD wallets.